# On a new PC with PCI 4.0 express SSD: Cloning or new install of Windows? Any performance differences?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, clone, windows-backup, clonezilla

I recently received a new laptop, my old one is really in a stage in which productive work is not possible anymore. The new laptop is equipped with an Nvidia GTX 4080 12 Gb and a 12900 processor and an upper level equipment option.

I purchased, however, a model with the basic RAM and SSD configuration and I am about to open the system to install the new ram and two 4TB SSDs. I just received a ESD mat to be extra careful not to damage any components. The original ssd is 1TB.

Now I am wondering: Is it better to clone the 1 TB drive that was shipped by the manufacturer or just to do a fresh windows install on the new SSD 4TB SSD after install?

Are there any problems in terms of sector allocation or any disadvantage in terms of performance when I directly clone instead of doing a fresh install?

It is a Dell PC and obviously the advantage of cloning is, that all drivers will be installed right away and there are probably less problems with windows activation I imagine. When I clone, and I am setting a sector provisioning first (5-7 Percent), is this provisioning actually considered by the cloning software or will the cloning start at sector 1 of the new drive with no provisioning after the copy?

I am considering to use Clonezilla and to connect the old drive with an SSD USB enclosure, so that I have to open the laptop just one time only.

Comment: On a new computer I'd do a new install as a general rule. However, note that your post appears to be asking multiple questions. They are related, but there are multiple questions. Please focus on a specific question, and not one that is a matter of preference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

Considering it's the same device, cloning probably would not cause any issues related to driver compatibility.

That said, I would still recommend that you do a clean Windows install, for 2 reasons:

1. Cloning the drive with incorrect settings might lead to the drive being cloned without the system reserved partition that contains important data that Windows needs for regular operation. I've had this happen in the past when I moved from a mechanical hard drive to an SSD, and while in my case it just lead to problems when upgrading to Windows 10, in your case it would lead to Windows not booting. You should be able to configure CloneZilla to avoid this, but it's still a risk.
2. Being a Dell laptop, it most likely shipped with a couple gigabytes of trial products that you don't need, stuff like an Office trial, a paid antivirus trial, low quality games, proprietary OEM software, and so on. In some cases, this software is a challenge to fully remove. A clean Windows install will remove all of that stuff without problems, and any drivers that might be missing can be reinstalled afterwards from the Dell website. You can even download the networking drivers beforehand on a USB drive to ensure you'll have internet afterwards.

Comment: Well, In clonezilla one must select a clone copy if I remember correctly with MTB sector to have a true sector to sector copy. Than the partition layout should be transfered fully including all the other partitions of windows, but I agree regarding the trials, there is a McAfee trial I neither need or want.